# Building a simple library with bazel, fixing include path

Tags: bazel

I have a very simple directory structure:

```
.
├── libs
│   └── foo
│       ├── BUILD
│       ├── include
│       │   └── foo
│       │       └── func.h
│       └── src
│           └── func.cxx
└── WORKSPACE
```

With `func.h`:

```
#pragma once

int square(int );
```

And `func.cxx`:

```
#include <foo/func.h>

int square(int i) { return i * i; }
```

And `BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/func.cxx"],
    hdrs = ["include/foo/func.h"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

This fails to build:

```
$ bazel build //libs/foo
INFO: Analysed target //libs/foo:foo (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/brevzin/sandbox/bazel/libs/foo/BUILD:1:1: C++ compilation of rule '//libs/foo:foo' failed (Exit 1)
libs/foo/src/func.cxx:1:22: fatal error: foo/func.h: No such file or directory
 #include <foo/func.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
Target //libs/foo:foo failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.299s, Critical Path: 0.02s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

How do I set the include path properly? I tried using `include_prefix` (whether `include` or `include/foo`) but that didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm, the tricky part about including headers from another places is that you have to specify the header file from its relative location according to the workspace (where the `WORKSPACE` file resides).

Moreover, you should not use the angle-bracket including style `#include <a/b.h>` unless you are including the system header files.

The related specifications for `#include` can be found here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-and-cpp.html#include-paths

**TL;DR** The only change you need to make to your `func.cxx` file is that, change the first line to `#include "libs/foo/include/foo/func.h"`.

And then, when you run `bazel build //...` (build all targets in this workspace, similar to `make` makes `all`) from the root of the workspace, you will encounter no error.

---

However, this is not the only way that can solve your problem.

Another way to resolve this issue that does not involve changing the source code include statement would be specifying the include path in the attribute of the rule `cc_library`.

Which means, you can make changes to your `BUILD` in path `libs/foo` to make it look like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/func.cxx"],
    hdrs = ["include/foo/func.h"],
    copts = ["-Ilibs/foo/include"], # This is the key part
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

After this change, the compiler will be able to figure out where to find the header file(s), and you don't have to change your source code, yay.

Related information can be found here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cpp-use-cases.html#adding-include-paths

---

Nevertheless, there is another hacky way to solve your problem, however, it involves in more changes to your code.

It makes uses of the rule `cc_inc_library`.

The rule `cc_inc_library` will strips `prefix` attribute passed to this rule from the relative path of the header files specified in the `hdrs` attribute.

The example on the website is a little confusing, your code and directory structure will yield a much better demonstration purpose.

In your case, you have to modify your `BUILD` file under `libs/foo` to something that looks like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/func.cxx"],
    deps = [":lib"],
    copts = ["-Ilibs/foo/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_inc_library(
    name = "lib",
    hdrs = ["include/foo/func.h"],
    prefix = "include/foo",
)
```

In your case, the header file `func.h` which has a relative path from the package `libs/foo` as `include/foo/func.h`, which is specified in the `hdrs` attribute.
Since it has a relative path to the root of the workspace as `libs/foo/include/foo/func.h`, and the `prefix` attribute in the `cc_inc_library` is specified as `include/foo`: the value `include/foo` will be stripped form `lib/foo/include/foo/func.h`, making it `libs/foo/func.h`.

So, now you can include this header file in your `func.cxx` as `#include "libs/foo/func.h"`.
And now, bazel will not report error saying that it was not able to find the header file.

You can find the information about this rule at: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_inc_library.
However, as stated above, the explanation is confusing at best, possibly because the documentation for it is out of date.

I was puzzled by the office explanation on `bazel.build` for quite some time until I read the source code for this rule at: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/f20ae6b20816df6a393c6e8352befba9b158fdf4/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcIncLibrary.java#L36-L50

The comment for the actual code that implements the function does a much, much better job at explaining what this rule actually does.

`cc_inc_library` rule has been deprecated since Bazel release 0.12.

Use `cc_library` approach instead.

See: https://blog.bazel.build/2018/04/11/bazel-0.12.html

Comment: In the case that the offending `#include <>` is inside a generated (i.e. via `genrule`) header, and the include path is relative to the root of the workspace, then this technique doesn't seem to be possible (would require `../` in the include path). However `copts = ["-I$(BINDIR)"]` in the dependant binary seems to do the trick, though it's not ideal.

Answer (score 6):

What you really want here is `strip_include_prefix`:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/func.cxx"],
    hdrs = ["include/foo/func.h"],
    # Here!
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

This will make the headers accessible via:

```c
#include "foo/func.h"
```

This attribute has been available since *at least* Bazel 0.17.

Comment: I guess this should really be the right answer, since it enables targets dependent on this one to build successfully should they try to include library headers without the full workspace path. using `copts` with `-I` will solve the problem only for this library, but will need to be repeated for every other target dependent on this library.