Bazel copts -I not adding path of header dependency
I am running into a problem building with Bazel. I have a main.c file which refers to my_header1.h and my_header_1.h refers to my_header2.h. When I try to build main.c I run into a No such file or directory error.
Here is the following folder structure:
|- c_example
|  |- src
|  |  |- BUILD
|  |  |- main.c
|  |
|  |- hdrs
|  |  |- hdr1
|  |  |  |- BUILD
|  |  |  |- my_header1.h
|  |  |
|  |  |- hdr2
|  |  |  |- BUILD
|  |  |  |- my_header2.h  

Here are the BUILD files:
main BUILD:
load(@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
   name="main",
   srcs=["main.c"],
   deps=["//c_example/hdrs/hdr1:my_header1"],
   copts=["-Ic_example/hdrs/hdr1"]

hdr1 BUILD:
load(@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
   name="my_header1",
   srcs=["my_header1.h"],
   deps=["//c_example/hdrs/hdr2:my_header2"],
   copts=["-Ic_example/hdrs/hdr2"],
   visibility=["//c_example/src:main"]

hdr2 BUILD:
load(@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
   name="my_header2",
   srcs=["my_header2.h"],
   visibility=["//c_example/hdrs/hdr1:my_header1"]

When I run bazel build c_example/src:main I get the following error:
c_example/hdrs/hdr1/my_header1.h:4:10: fatal error: my_header2.h: No such file or directory
   4 | #include "my_header2.h"
     |
compilation terminated
Target //c_example/src:main failed to build

It seems like copts -I flag is not including the path to the second header file. But I do not know why! Can anyone help out? Thanks!
Also, I recreated a very simple example for a LOT more files I'm working with. In short, the folder/file structure has to stay to what I have shown.

In your example, adding "-Ic_example/hdrs/hdr2" to the copts of the main cc_library will make it compile. However, my recommendation is include using full path "#include "hdrs/hdr1/my_header.1.h" and completely lose the copts. See https://bazel.build/docs/bazel-and-cpp#include-paths and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915433/building-a-simple-library-with-bazel-fixing-include-path
